# Design patterns/advise on building a Rule engine

Tags: ruby, dsl, rules, business-rules, rule-engine

I have a need to build an app (Ruby) that allows the user to select one or more patterns and in case those patterns are matched to proceed and complete a set of actions.
While doing my research I've discovered the new (to me) field of rules based systems and have spent some time reading about it and it seems exactly the kind of functionality I need.

The app will be integrated with different web services and would allow rules like these one:

When Highrise contact is added and Zendesk ticket is created do add email to database

I had two ideas to build this. The first is to build some kind os DSL to be able to specify the rule conditions and build them on the fly with the user input.

The second one is to build some rule classes each one having a pattern/matcher and action methods. The pattern would evaluate the expression and return true or false and the action would be executed if the match is positive.

The rules will then need to be persisted and then evaluated periodically.

Can anyone shed some light on this design or point somewhere where I can get more information on this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a commercial rules engine e.g. Drools, FlexRule... the pattern matching  is handled by RETE algorithm. And also, some of them provide multiple different engines for different logic e.g. procedural, validation, inference, flow, workflow,... and they also provide DSL customization... 
Rule sequencing and execution is handled based on agenda and activation that can be defined on the engine. And conflict resolution strategy would help you to find proper activation to fire.

I recommend you to use a commercial product hosting on a host/service. And use simple Json/Xml format to communicate to the rule server and execute your rules. This will be giving you a better result probably than creating your own one. However if you are interested in creating your own one as a pattern matching engine consider RETE algorithm, agenda and activation mechanisms for complex production system.

In RETE algorithm you may consider at least implementing Positive and Negative conditions. In implementing RETE you need to implement beta and alpha memories as well ad join nodes that supports left and right activations.

Answer (score 0):

Do you think you could represent your problem in a graph-based representation? I'm pretty sure that your problem can be considered as a graph-based problem

If yes, why don't you use a graph transformation system to define and apply you rules. The one that I would recommend is GrGen.NET. The use of GrGen.NET builds on five steps

1. **Definition of the metamodel:** Here, you define you building blocks, i.e. types of graph nodes and graph edges.
2. **Definition of the ruleset:** This is where you can put your pattern detecting rules. Moreover, you can create rule encapsulating procedures to manipulate your graph-based data structure.
3. **Compilation:** Based on the previous two steps, a C#-assembly (DLL) is created. There should be a way to access such a DLL from Ruby.
4. **Definition of a rule sequence:** Rule sequences contain the structure in which individual rules are executed. Typically, it's a logical structure in which the rules are concatenated.
5. **Graph transformation:** The application of a rule sequences on a DLL results in the transformation of a graph that can subsequently be exported, saved or further manipulated.

You can find a very good manual of GrGen.NET here: http://www.info.uni-karlsruhe.de/software/grgen/GrGenNET-Manual.pdf